# Многопоточность. Лучший способ

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task, snmp

Стоит задача сделать программу мониторинга железок  по SNMP(не спрашивайте зачем, сам в шоке)
Планирую использовать c# и библиотеку SNMP lex.
Мониториться могут много железок, сотня, а то и больше. Каждая железка имеет кучу параметров для мониторинга.

Хотел сделать так. Мониторинг каждого параметра запускается в отдельном Task в бесконечном цикле и параметр опрашивается каждые 5 секунд.

Выглядит это ужасно, поскольку 100 железок на 20 параметров, итого 2000 тасков с бесконечным циклом.

Посоветуйте, как лучше решить задачу?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81690/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Comment: что если использовать Timer.Elapsed для запуска каждого запроса со своим интервалом повтора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что вы будете запрашивать информацию асинхронно. 
Например, так

```
static Random r = new Random();
public Task<int> GetDeviceParameter(int deviceId, int parameterId)
{
  return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t=>r.Next());
}
```

Я предположил, что запрос занимает 1 секунду. Теперь запросим 20 параметров по конкретному девайсу

```
public Task<int[]> ReadDeviceParameters(int decviceId)
{
  var tasks = new Task<int>[20];

  for(var i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    tasks[i] = GetDeviceParameter(decviceId, i);
  }

  return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Все вроде просто. Запросим это для 100 девайсов

```
public Task<int[][]> ReadParameters()
{
  var tasks = new Task<int[]>[100];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    tasks[i] = ReadDeviceParameters(i);
  }

  return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Теперь, как оранизовать цикл? Нам, наверное, надо иметь токен отмены для цикла и засекать время, чтобы цикл запускался каждые 5 секунд, но после отработки предыдущих запросов.

```
public async Task ReadParametersLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
  while(!token.IsCancellationRequested) 
  { 
    var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting read at {start:mm:ss}");

    await ReadParameters(); 

    var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var diff = end - start;
    var delay = (int)Math.Min(5000, 5000 - diff.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading ens at {end:mm:ss}, took {diff}, delay for {delay}");

    if (delay > 0)
      await Task.Delay(delay);
  }
}
```

Запускаю это в консоли на 15 секунд

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
await ReadParametersLoop(cts.Token);
```

Получаю результат

```
Starting read at 29:56
Reading ens at 29:57, took 00:00:01.0061006, delay for 3993
Starting read at 30:01
Reading ens at 30:02, took 00:00:01.0161016, delay for 3983
Starting read at 30:06
Reading ens at 30:07, took 00:00:01.0161016, delay for 3983
```

Таким образом, если запросы отрабатывают меньше, чем за 5 секунд (в сумме), то они стабильно запрашиваются каждые 5 секунд.

Comment: Как запустить? await ReadParametersLoop(cts.Token); просит чтобы метод был асинхронным, если сделать метод Main асинхронным, то тогда ругается  Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства  требуется ссылка на объект. Простите за глупые вопросы, слишком мало опыта у меня.

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов ну оберните методы в класс и создавайте класс внутри метода Main или сделайте методы статическими - как вам удобней :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться реактивными расширениями [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/)

Небольшой пример как работать с мониторингом параметров используя `IObservable`
Вместо `Dictionary` с параметрами, можно создать отдельный класс.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start: {DateTime.Now}");
        var parameters = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => $"Parameter {x}").ToArray();
        var devices = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(x => $"Device {x}").ToArray();

        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            var monitor = Observable.FromAsync(() => GetParametersAsync(parameters))
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Repeat();

            monitor.Subscribe(x => HandleParameters(device, x));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Пример обработки параметров
    /// </summary>
    private static void HandleParameters(string device, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{device} {parameter.Key}: {parameter.Value}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetParametersAsync(string[] parameterIds)
    {
        var parameters = parameterIds.Select(parameterId => new { Id = parameterId, Task = GetParameterAsync(parameterId) }).ToList();
        var tasks = parameters.Select(x => x.Task).ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            results.Add(parameter.Id, parameter.Task.Result);
        }
        return results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Эмуляция получения данных
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<string> GetParameterAsync(string parameterId) 
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде работает, надо думать, как прикрутить к своему. Не совсем понимаю код, поскольку очень мало опыта.

Comment: На каждую железку вы создаете монитор (который будет наблюдать за параметрами, реализация шаблона "Наблюдатель", по сути будет дергать метод GetParametersAsync, с задержкой которую вы указали в Delay(), вызов будут повторяться, так как вы указали Repeat()). Дальше на монитор в повесили обработчика (Наблюдателя) в методе Subscribe()
Ну и метод GetParametersAsync Асинхронно вызывает  GetParameterAsync для коллекции parameterIds

Comment: Документация на IObservable https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: если так 
public static async Task<string> GetParameterAsync(Sensor sensor) Вместо (string parameterId)
Как остальной код переписать?

Comment: Это всего лишь пример, вместо GetParameterAsync вы можете вызывать свой async метод из библиотеки, вы писали что он у вас есть

Comment: хмм, разве `monitor.Subscribe(..)` не возвращает подписку, которую нужно сохранить где то (чтобы GC её не удалил)?

Comment: Вообще да, но возвращает наоборот чтобы отписаться когда закончите работу с монитором. То есть подписали observer-ы, они отработали, вы их отписываете и например подписываете новые. Но тут по логике отписывать ничего не требуется. GC observer-ы не удалятся так как они добавлены в list внутри монитора.